# Migration of Nested reducers in @ngrx/store from v2 to v4+

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have legacy code that is implemented in @ngrx/store v2.2.3 and angular v4.4. I have upgraded my project to angular v11 which requires @ngrx/store v4+ library. The old codes fails as we used nested reducer implementation. I looked into https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v4 but still not useful.

```
// reducers/order.ts
export function orderReducer(state = [], action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CLEAR: 
      return [];
    case CREATE_ORDER:
      return ...;
    case DELETE_ORDER: 
      return ...;
    case GET_ORDERS: 
      return ...;
    case UPDATE_ORDER: 
      return ...;
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}
export function reprintedOrdersReducer(state = [], action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_PRINTED_ORDERS: 
      return ...;
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}
export const orderReducers = combineReducers({
  order : orderReducer, 
  reprint: reprintedOrdersReducer,
});
```

```
// reducers/delivery.ts
export function deliveryReducer(state = [], action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CLEAR: 
      return [];
    case CREATE_DELIVERY:
      return ...;
    case DELETE_DELIVERY: 
      return ...;
    case GET_DELIVERY_LIST: 
      return ...;
    case UPDATE_DELIVERY: 
      return ...;
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}
export function reprintedDeliveryReducer(state = [], action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_PRINTED_DELIVERY_LIST: 
      return ...;
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}
export const deliveryReducers = combineReducers({
  delivery : deliveryReducer, 
  reprint: reprintedDeliveryReducer,
});
```

```
// reducers/index.ts
import { orderReducers } from './order';
import { deliveryReducers } from './delivery';

const reducers = {
  order      : orderReducers,
  delivery   : deliveryReducers
}
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
export function rootReducer(state: any, action: any) {
   return reducer(state, action);
}
```

```
// app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
     ...
     StoreModule.provideStore(rootReducer),
     StoreDevtoolsModule.instrumentStore({ maxAge: 15 }),
     ...
  ]
})
```

```
// order.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class OrderService {
   constructor(private store: Store<any>) {}

   getCurrentlyDueOrders(): Observable<any> {
      return this.store.select('order', 'reprint');
   }
}
```

@ngrx/store v4+ (v4.1.1) library implementation is completely changed and I have made few changes like,

- StoreModule.forRoot(rootReducer),
- StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 15 }),

but still the build fails with following error.

```
Error: src/app/app.module.ts(90,25): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'combineReducers' was called in 'rootReducer'
    'rootReducer' references 'orderReducers' at src/app/reducers/index.ts(18,18)
      'orderReducers' calls 'combineReducers' at src/app/reducers/order.ts(43,30).
```